# How do I select the first record from an inner query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table (call it `OBJ_EVENTS`) like this:

```
EVENT_ID    OBJ_ID     EVENT_DATE     EVENT_TYPE

500         1          10/10/2010     FOO
497         1          01/05/2011     BAR
714         1          01/06/2011     BAZ
1700        2          01/01/2012     FOO
57          2          08/09/2012     BAR
12          2          08/10/2010     BAZ
```

Important note - my `EVENT_ID` column is **not ordered**

And I'd like to execute a SQL query to display the time difference between FOO events and bar events like this:

```
OBJ_ID     FOO_TIME      BAR_TIME

1          10/10/2010    01/05/2011
2          01/01/2012    08/09/2012
```

When I originally wrote this query, my `EVENT_ID` was ordered, so I did something like this:

```
SELECT E1.OBJ_ID,
       E1.EVENT_DATE AS FOO_TIME,
       E2.EVENT_DATE AS BAR_TIME
  FROM OBJ_EVENTS E1
  JOIN OBJ_EVENTS E2
    ON (E2.EVENT_ID = (SELECT MIN(EVENT_ID)
                         FROM OBJ_EVENTS E3
                        WHERE E3.OBJ_ID = E1.OBJ_ID
                          AND E3.EVENT_DATE >= E1.EVENT_DATE
                          AND E3.EVENT_TYPE = 'BAR'))
```

However, due to other project constraints that I won't go into, my `EVENT_ID` is no longer chronologically ordered, so this query doesn't work. I also tried doing an `order by E3.EVENT_DATE` and selecting where row_number() = 1, but that doesn't work either. Oracle throws an error.

Help!!!

Comment: you could do a min (E3.EVENT_DATE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want the FOO events and their subsequent BAR events. Try the "lead" analytic function to get the subsequent BAR.

```
select event_type, next_type, event_date, next_date, next_date - event_date  from (
  select obj_id, event_date, event_type, 
         lead(event_type) over (partition by obj_id order by event_date) next_type,
         lead(event_date) over (partition by obj_id order by event_date) next_date
  from 
  event_test 
  where event_type in ('FOO', 'BAR')
) where event_type = 'FOO' and next_type='BAR'
```

Will give you this:

```
1   1   FOO BAR 10/10/2010  1/5/2011    87
2   2   FOO BAR 1/1/2012    8/9/2012    221
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one foo event and one bar event per `obj_id`, then your query is overly complicated:

```
select ef.obj_id, ef.event_date as event_date_foo, eb.event_date as event_date_bar
from obj_events ef join
     obj_events eb
     on ef.obj_id = eb.obj_id and
        ef.event_type = 'FOO' and
        eb.event_type = 'BAR';
```

If there are multiple occurrences, you need to decide which you want.  This one gets the first occurrence for each:

```
select e.obj_id,
       min(case when e.event_type = 'FOO' then event_date end) as event_date_foo,
       min(case when e.event_type = 'BAR' then event_date end) as event_date_bar
from obj_events e
group by e.obj_id;
```

I assume you know how to take the difference of the dates, because you already have a query that once worked.

Comment: In my database, there could be an entire stream of FOO and BAR events. I need to display the time of the next closest BAR for each FOO.

Comment: Your second suggestion will not work for me because I need to join the obj_events table in so I can do arithmetic on the dates.